# dns lookup VS HTTP Parallel downloads

Tags: performance, http, web-applications, yslow

HTTP 1.1 allows 2 connections per host name. On the other hand, [yahoo performance rules](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#dns_lookups) suggest to reduce the number of DNS look ups.

how does one balance this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article *(unfortunatly, quite old, as it's from 2007 ; but it still seems to be reasonable)*, might help you : [Performance Research, Part 4: Maximizing Parallel Downloads in the Carpool Lane](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/04/11/performance-research-part-4/) ; quoting the last paragraph :

> Our rule of thumb is to **increase the
>   number of parallel downloads by using
>   at least two, but no more than four
>   hostnames**. Once again, this
>   underscores the number one rule for
>   improving response times: reduce the
>   number of components in the page.

But read the article : there are some other interesting reflexions and resutls of experimentations.